# Jackson throws NPE during deserialization on missing property

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I'm still getting NPE while trying to deserialize an JSON. I wish to put a default value (0 / null) if property is missing. This is my Spring Boot configuration bean:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
    return jsonConverter;
}

ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
    simpleModule.addDeserializer(ProductBasicDto.class, new ProductDeserializer());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, false);

    mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
    return mapper;
}
```

My custom deserializer:

```
@Override
public ProductBasicDtoWrapper deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
    System.out.println(node.get("id").asLong()); // here it throws NPE
 return null; // ignore that, just for testing
}
```

json:

```
{
  "name": "js",
  "category": "CoNiFer"
}
```

and execption:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at api.product.infrastructure.ProductDeserializer.deserialize(ProductDeserializer.java:19)
at api.product.infrastructure.ProductDeserializer.deserialize(ProductDeserializer.java:14)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3072)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:235)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:223)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:157)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:130)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
```

1. How can I avoid this NPE?
2. Is it possible to put 0 / null values without explict checks in deserializer if property(like id in this example) is missing?

EDIT: Added some code examples

Let's say this is my DTO class:

```
class MyDto implements Serializable {
private final String firstName;
private final String lastName;
}
```

Now I'm creating my custom mapper:

```
@Override
public ProductBasicDtoWrapper deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, 
DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, 
JsonProcessingException {
 objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNode, MyDto.class);
```

...

Now I decided to add additional Integer to MyDto:

```
    class MyDto implements Serializable {
private final String firstName;
private final String lastName;
private final Integer age;
}
```

It's great it doesn't needs changing ANYTHING else (in my mapper class). But assume I got this kind of json

```
 {
   "firstName": "name"
}
```

Now it throws NPE. So the idea is to check if values are null in mapper. Let's do it:

```
@Override
public ProductBasicDtoWrapper deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, 
DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, 
JsonProcessingException {
JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
  node.get("firstName") == null ?
  node.get("lastName") == null ?
  node.get("age") == null ?
```

}

Okay it works, now let's say I added one more attribute to my DTO class

```
class MyDto implements Serializable {
private final String firstName;
private final String lastName;
private final Integer age;
private final String card;
```

}

The problem is, in this case I have to change ALSO my mapper class because 4th parameter isn't handled.

Comment: I edited the answer acording to your edit.

Comment: Ohh you remind me why i decided to NOT use solution with object mapper configuration. In this case I can't make my fields final. I need immutable dto's. I know in this simple example it is immutable but let's assume i have there collections or  whatever what can change its state

Comment: You should have said that at the beginning, I edited again.

Comment: It looks like is the only solution which meet my requirements right? I knew it can be done with annotations but It looks terrible for me, it's why I'm looking for some alternatives. Actually i have declared many different constructors in my dto and when I look at it now it looks even worse than these annotations.. : P okay thank you so much for help :)

Comment: I think that's the only way for immutables, and at least to me it doesn't look that bad, and it is definitely better than having multiple constructors. Jackson has to know some way the names of the properties, when used with a Pojo it finds out the name from the setter, but in an immutable object, there are no setters so you have to explicitly indicate the name of the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line returns null

```
node.get("id") // returns null when property is not defined
```

Because the property is obviouly not defined in the JSON. You can resolve your problem in many ways, but you will always have to check null when using `get(name)` and one of the methods asLong, asString, etc, or just check if the property is defined with `has(name)`.

You can also use a helper function

```
public static Long getLong(JsonNode node, String name) {
    if (node.get(name) != null && node.get(name).isLong()) {
        return node.get(name).asLong();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can return null, or throw an exception, if you return null you should be carefull and handle it later.

And then use it to print the variable or null when not defined.

```
System.out.println(getLong(node, "id"));
```

**EDIT (Acording to the edited question):**

When you configure the object mapper you can specify how strict it should be with the configure method, you could use the DeserializationFeature enum to indicate when it should fail and when it shouldn't.

Here you can see each feature and what is for:
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html

Now if the name of the properties in your class and json matches you can convert a json to a dto object just as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper() // object mapper with wanted properties
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false)
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, false)
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, false)
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, 

mapper.readValue(json, MyDto.class);
```

Here you just need to create the mapper (no deserializer is needed) and then transform it to the destination class.

In case you have different names in you class and json you have to use the annotation @JsonProperty and specify the name.

**Possible problems:**

Now, for what I can see in your DTO your using final attributes, when you use them you have to create a constructor with arguments, and cannot create an empty contructor (at least without specified it's values beforehand), this empty constructor is necessary for a java POJO and is used internally by the object mapper.

So your DTO should be something like:

```
class MyDto implements Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer age;
    // empty constructor (only necessary when another constructor is specified)
    // getters and setters
}
```

If you still need to use Immutable objects and not POJOs you can create a class like the following:

```
class MyDto implements Serializable {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final Integer age;
    @JsonCreator
    MyDto(@JsonProperty("firstName") String firstName,
          @JsonProperty("lastName") String lastName,
          @JsonProperty("age") Integer age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
    // getters
}
```

**Using the mapper**

With the POJO class and object mapper from above you can do the following:

```
MyDto myDto1 = mapper.readValue("{\"firstName\": \"name\"}", MyDto.class); // object with firstName defined, lastName and age are null
MyDto myDto2 = mapper.readValue("{\"firstName\": \"name\",\"lastName\": \"last\"}", MyDto.class); // object with firstName and lastName defined, age is null
MyDto myDto3 = mapper.readValue("{\"firstName\": \"name\",\"lastName\": \"last\",\"age\": 1}", MyDto.class); // object with firstName, lastName and age defined
```

And you can even use an empty object or have unknown properties.

```
MyDto myDto4 = mapper.readValue("{}", MyDto.class); // object with all properties null
MyDto myDto5 = mapper.readValue("{\"blablah\": \"name\"}", MyDto.class); // object with all properties null
```

Comment: In this case I can't create any generic mapping mechanism without reflection api? Every time when i add attribute (let's say additional String field) to DTO then I have to include it in my mapper class too right?

Comment: Here the reflection api is not used. What do you want to do exactly? if you want to convert the json node to ProductBasicDtoWrapper you do not need to add a deserializer just use `objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNode, ProductBasicDtoWrapper.class);` or `objectMapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, ProductBasicDtoWrapper.class);`

Comment: how it behaves in case when jsonNode is null?

Comment: Well it throws but that does not make any sense, Why would you pass null? you said properties could be missing not the entire jsonnode. Anyway just pass an empty json node with `mapper.createObjectNode()` when jsonnode is null.

Comment: So we came back to the beginning, i have to explict check if attribute is missing.

Comment: It's not the atribbute it's the entire json... JsonNode hold all the atribbutes not just one. PD. Use the code and tell me if it works. Do not pass JsonNode null because it does not make any sense, if you pass JsonNode null we are not talking about missing properties we are talking of no properties at all.

Comment: I was talking about attributes in my DAO class, because in case when I have to explict check if value is null then I MUST  KNOW HOW MANY ATTRIBUTES I HAVE TO CHECK. Maybe I should add some code example to make it more clear

Comment: Yes you should. You don't have to check any attributes ever, you only check the jsonnode once. so is as simple as `mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode != null ? jsonNode : mapper.createObjectNode(), ProductBasicDtoWrapper.class)` that is all the code you need, don't have to check specific properties...

Comment: added example--